# Change number of decimal places of upcoming float prints

Tags: c#

I have some code which logs data using string interpolation. For the sake of the example, it's something like this:

```
public void LogData() {
   logger.Info($"{floatValue1}, {floatValue2}, {boolValue}, {intValue}");
}
```

Sometimes when I call this code, I want it to display with just a couple of decimal places. However, sometimes I would like to get a higher number of decimal places. I know that you can set the number of decimal places manually like `$"{floatValue1:0.00}"` or `$"{floatValue1:0.0000000}"`. However, I want to programatically set the number of decimal places before call the logging code. So, something like this:

```
//detailed log
DecimalFormatting.DecimalPlaceCount = 6;
obj.LogData();
```

```
//concise log
DecimalFormatting.DecimalPlaceCount = 2;
obj.LogData();
```

I don't want to, and in some cases can't change the code inside of `LogData()`

Is this possible?

I couldn't find any other questions regarding this, however I'm sure that's just because I didn't know what to search for.

Comment: The `LogData` program you show references `floatValue1`, etc.  Where are they declared and typed.  Can you change that?  One option is to change the `floatValueN` to be strings and preformat them.  If you can't change anything, it's going to be hard to change this

Answer (score 1):

You may use [this `string` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_) to create the format based on the given number, and then use that format for each float value.

Try something like the following:

```
public void LogData() 
{
    string format = $"0.{new string('0', DecimalFormatting.DecimalPlaceCount)}";
    //                              ^^^
    // Use '#' if you want to set the **maximum** number of decimal places
    logger.Info($"{floatValue1.ToString(format)}, {floatValue2.ToString(format)}, {boolValue}, {intValue}");
}
```

You can also make it more elegant for your particular logging format:

```
logger.Info(string.Join(", ",
    floatValue1.ToString(format),
    floatValue2.ToString(format),
    boolValue,
    intValue));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Sorry I didn't make it clear in the initial post, but I can't change the code within the `LogData()` method. I have edited the question to reflect this!

Comment: @hugeandy If you can't alter the `LogData()` method in any way whatsoever, then I'm afraid you're stuck with the default format (i.e., `G`). If you can change the code in `LogData()` to at least use `{floatValue1:N}`, then there might be things you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a huge variety in your logs, i.e. you want "either 2 or 6 decimal places" some bool on the logger would do:

```
class Logger

  public bool PreciseDecimals {get; set;}

  ...

  public void LogData() {
    if(PreciseDecimals)
      logger.Info($"{floatValue1:F6}, {floatValue2:F6}, {boolValue}, {intValue}");
    else
      logger.Info($"{floatValue1:F2}, {floatValue2:F2}, {boolValue}, {intValue}");
  }
```

If you do want a huge variety:

```
class Logger

  private string _f = "F0";
  public int NumDP {
    get => int.Parse(_f[1..]); 
    set => _f = "F" + value;
  }

  ...

  public void LogData() {
      logger.Info($"{floatValue1.ToString(_f)}, {floatValue2.ToString(_f)}, {boolValue}, {intValue}");
  }
```

You might want to put some restriction on the setter of NumDP to ensure it's in the range 0-99

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Sorry I didn't make it clear in the initial post, but I can't change the code within the `LogData()` method. I have edited the question to reflect this!

Comment: Oh.. In that case, you're screwed. Why can't you change it? Can you add another method? Can you subclass the logger and get in the way of the calls?

Comment: Some of the `LogData()` methods don't exist within our code base so that's why I can't change them/add methods. I have added an answer which does half of what I want, but it assumes that the external string formats use 'F' or 'N' *without* explicity specifying the number of decimal places (like 'F1').

Comment: How does the code come to know about the logger class? Tell me more as to what it is, what library it's from, how it gets in the program and give some examples of cases where it's "not your codebase". I'm also leaning towards just reparsing the produced log file and modifying it again

Answer (score 0):

The closest and cleanest I have got to what I want is modifying the current culture and changing `NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits` as shown below.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
                    
public class Program {
    private static float a = 1.23456f;
    private static float b = 1.2f;
    
    private static CultureInfo currentCulture;
    
    public static void Main() {
        currentCulture = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
        
        LogDataWithSpecifiedDecimalPlaces(3);
        LogDataWithSpecifiedDecimalPlaces(6);
    }
    
    private static void LogData() {
        Console.WriteLine($"{a:N} {b:F}");
    }
    
    private static void LogDataWithSpecifiedDecimalPlaces(int decimalPlaces = 2) {
        currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = decimalPlaces;
        LogData();
    }
}
```

This yields

```
1.235 1.200
1.234560 1.200000
```

However, it does require that the string format uses specifier 'N' or 'F'. Using no format specifier does not work with this method, and seems to print out as many decimal places as it needes to show the number (i.e. 1.2 shows as "1.2" and 1.2345 shows as "1.2345").

Comment: I did think to make a suggestion along the lines of changing the culture settings for the thread, program or even the entire machine but I thought "nah.. that's just a bit too 'out there'"